# Jupyter Notebook: Toggle button for hide/show code blocks in HTML export

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I've been searching for a few days and I've got it down to the following:

You can make a whole JupyterBook and add extensions to the conf.py file to indicate toggle blocks - then export it to HTML through a build command.

However, though Jupyter books are cool, this seems super overkill and long winded. If I had a small single Jupyter notebook is there a way I can add on to make the a toggle button for the code inblocks which persist when the notebook is exported to html.

Is there a simple guide somewhere to achieve this, all within a single Jupyter Notebook - then export to html?